# I removed security groups from RDS but access still exists from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I removed security groups for RDS, left access only for my IP. But access from EC2(ECS Fargate) still exists. Where I do have to look in order to fix it?

UPD:

I removed security groups from Connectivity tab in RDS > Databases Modify DB instance: ****

UPD2:

I have only one group: DevGroup
with only one rule

MYSQL/Aurora    TCP 3306    x.x.x.x/32 (my home IP)

Comment: You removed them from where? Can you show these SGs?

Comment: @Marcin from Connectivity tab in RDS > Databases
Modify DB instance: ****

Comment: I think it would be better to update your question with all the details.

Comment: I mean, what are the actuall rules in the SGs. Your question lacks details.

Comment: Did you actually apply these changes immediately? By default such changes are postponed to maintenance window.

Comment: @Marcin yes, I applied these changes immediately.

Comment: How are you connecting from the Amazon EC2 instance to the Amazon RDS database? If the Amazon RDS database does not have a security group permitting such access, then there will be no connectivity. It is possible that you changed the database configuration **but the change has not been applied**. You can check the database status to see whether changes are pending. See: [Modifying an Amazon RDS DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that removing the security group from RDS didn't immediately affect it. After while access has gone.

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html#USER_VPC.Scenario1

Instances in the same VPC have access there is no need to configure security groups there

Comment: This is incorrect. Resources in the same VPC cannot access each other unless permitted by an associated Security Group.